# Tkinter: not getting mouse events to parent

Tags: python, background, tkinter, mouseevent

I am attempting to modify a script to make it borderless, but I am stuck on getting mouse events to the parts of the parent widget which do not have child widgets on top....

```
class Application:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.overrideredirect(True)
        self.root.attributes( '-topmost', 1 ) #always on top
        self.root.title('ReaChorder')
        ttk.Frame(self.root, borderwidth=5, relief="sunken", width=740,height=300)#.pack()
        self.init_widgets()


    def init_widgets(self):
        fn = (my_path + '/bg_740x300.gif') ;  self.bg = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file=fn)
        self.bgLabel = ttk.Label(self.root, image=self.bg)
        self.bgLabel.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.bgLabel.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.StartMove)
        self.bgLabel.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.StopMove)
        self.bgLabel.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.OnMotion)
        self.bgLabel.pack()
        self.bgLabel.pack_propagate(False)

        self.btns = ttk.Button(self.bgLabel,  text='Draw chords into MIDI take...', width='25')
        self.btns.place(x=562, y=260) 
        self.btns.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.drawMidiNow())
```

... none of the mouse events bound to bgLabel are called.  Could somebody be so kind as to point out the schoolboy error?

Comment: Can you give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)—a full, running example that demonstrates the problem, but with all the extraneous stuff stripped out?

Comment: Also, what Python version, and what platform? When I try to build a simple program around this fragment, it seems to work fine, but I have no idea whether that's because my additional code is different from yours, or because your code depends on platform-dependent behavior and my platform is different from yours, or…

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It is a script running within an audio sequencer called REAPER x86, using Python 2.7.5 x86 on Windows 7 x64.  I'll get an SSCCE together and get back....

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you claim you're having. When I click on the label I see that `StartMove`, `StopMove` and `OnMotion` get called as expected.

Comment: I came back to this after a break and saw there was a blank tkinter window lurking behind the one created by the app.  When I closed it, ended the script and reloaded the host app I can see the methods are now being called.  Sorry for wasting everybody's time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that events are only reported on the widget on which they happen? If you set a binding on a label, that event will only fire if your mouse is over that label. If you want events to be processed on the parent, you need to set the bindings on the parent, too.

Comment: Thanks, yes the parent is the label I am talking about in this instance.